# Parse serialized form data from jQuery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, serialization

I am using jQuery to serialize form data on submit. I have the data in this form:

```
address1=1+Station+Circle&address2=&address3=&town_city=Pittsburg
&zipcode=02113&subentity=Buyster+AUS&general_location=&contact=Vince+Seiser
&phone=349-502-7267&fax=617-532-6800&email=dev%40something.com&selectbox1=1
```

I am trying to parse this in PHP using parse_str, but it doesn't work. Any other ways to do that?

Comment: Show how you are sending that data (js) and attempting to retrieve it (php).

Comment: these `&address2=&address3=&general_location=`don't have a value,add some values o them or remove them

Comment: Setting a value as ` ` is a value... in PHP, `&var1=&var2..`.means that var1 is set, but is empty... being present and empty might be important or even part of the logic

Comment: Show your code, both client and server side.  Tell us where in your code the behavior differs from what you expect.  Chances are you shouldn't have to manually use `parse_str()` on the server side if you are passing the query string correctly from client.

Answer (score 0):

Try the function:  urldecode()
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no return from `parse_str` you just access the variables parsed from the string.

```
print $town_city;
// Pittsburg
```

`parse_str` is working just fine, take a look below.

```
parse_str($str);

var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

This is the relevant part of the output.

```
  ["str"]=>
  string(211) "address=StationCircle&address2=&address3=&town_city=Pittsburg&zipcode=02113&subentity=Buyster+AUS&general_location=&contact=Vince+Seiser&phone=349-502-7267&fax=617-532-6800&email=dev%40something.com&selectbox1=1"
  ["address"]=>
  string(13) "StationCircle"
  ["address2"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["address3"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["town_city"]=>
  string(9) "Pittsburg"
  ["zipcode"]=>
  string(5) "02113"
  ["subentity"]=>
  string(11) "Buyster AUS"
  ["general_location"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["contact"]=>
  string(12) "Vince Seiser"
  ["phone"]=>
  string(12) "349-502-7267"
  ["fax"]=>
  string(12) "617-532-6800"
  ["email"]=>
  string(17) "dev@something.com"
  ["selectbox1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
```